# Layout not rendering properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My bootstrap layout is not rendering properly after updated the chrome version (Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) unknown (64-bit)) in Ubuntu 18, and also not working after updating Windows machine Chrome.

I am using Bootstrap 3 and grid layout, and it successfully running on Firefox and Safari browser. before it is working on all platform, but right now it is not working on Chrome.

When I open inspect element in that case it is also not working sometime

Here is my attached images:

[image]

It look like this:

[image]

Updated screenshot with error:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code to debug ?

Comment: @tarunkhosla i have attached the screenshot you check it, and i am using 'scrolling-content' classs for scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade your browser.

Disclaimer: with the specifications and context provided, it is the only (working!) solution.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have attached updated screenshot, you can check it.
I can not share my all code because it is too long, and i can not downgrade my  version because project is live.

Comment: Yeah yeah. My answer is just sarcastic way of saying that you should work on your sample. Have you tried anything? You. Can start with creating minimal reproduction exaple in codepen or jsfiddle or similar. Or you can just read chrome changelog to find some clues.